# How to draw text parallel to Bar of BarChartView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to achieve the functionality to show the win and loss percent of every month parallel to the bar. Please provide any suggestion.

I am using [danielgindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

[image: Bar Chart with parallel Label]

I am trying to achive the this functinality.
here is the chart setup code:

```
    chartView.legend.enabled = true
    chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    chartView.maxVisibleCount = 12
    chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
    chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = false
    chartView.delegate = self
    chartView.dragEnabled = true
    chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = true
    chartView.noDataTextColor  = .black
    chartView.highlightFullBarEnabled = true
    chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false

    chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

    chartView.xAxis.enabled = true
    chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    chartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
    chartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(months.count, force: false)
    chartView.xAxis.granularity = 1

    let l = chartView.legend
    l.horizontalAlignment = .center
    l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
    l.orientation = .horizontal
    l.drawInside = false
    l.xEntrySpace = 5
    l.yEntrySpace = 2
    l.yOffset = 5
    l.xOffset = 20
```

here i am assigning the value to chart

```
 let yVals = (0..<data.count).map { (i) -> BarChartDataEntry in
        let val1 = Double(data[i].ownopportunityOwn.roundToOneDigitCroreValue)
        let val2 = Double(data[i].ownopportunityAssistby.roundToOneDigitCroreValue)
        return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [val1, val2])
    }

    let set = BarChartDataSet(values: yVals, label: "")
    set.drawIconsEnabled = false
    set.colors = [AppColors.Graph_LightGreenColor,AppColors.Graph_PurpleColor]
    set.roundedCorners = [.topLeft,.topRight]

    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
    data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 7, weight: .bold))
    data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
    data.setValueTextColor(.white)
    chartView.fitBars = true

    chartView.data = data

    var array = [LegendEntry]()

    var legendValueArray = [(title: DashboardConstant.K_OWN_WINS.value, Color: AppColors.Graph_LightGreenColor),(title: DashboardConstant.K_ASSISTED_BY_WIN.value, Color: AppColors.Graph_PurpleColor)]

    for object in legendValueArray {
        array.append( LegendEntry(label: object.title, form: .square, formSize: 10, formLineWidth: 1, formLineDashPhase: 1, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: object.Color))
    }
    self.chartView.legend.setCustom(entries: array)
    self.chartView.fitScreen()
    self.chartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 3, yAxisDuration: 3)
```

Comment: @mag_zbc I am asking is this possible to achieve using graph library. rotating label is not the solution to this problem.

Comment: Quite difficult to know what you are doing and how, considering you didn't post any code whatsoever

Comment: @mag_zbc please have a look at the code.

Comment: @NitinSingh - since the Charts library you are using is Open Source, you can simply add that "feature" yourself.